# How to handle framework with dev and release versions in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, drm, widevine

In my project I am using a framework which contain simulator,dev and release version.How can I test the release sdk?What are the particulars that I have to check?

As far as I know ,I can change the scheme and create a release build.I want to know if it will automatically choose the release sdk or not?

Or do I have to create an archive  and install as ipa file?If I can install the app via xcode do I have to remove the cable and launch the app manually?

Comment: When you run on the device choose the Release scheme and run it. Archive will automatically pickup Release of the scheme selected.

Comment: While using release build please remove the USB cable from device and launch the video manually.I read the above statement in the sdk documentation.It is causing the confusion.

Comment: @satheeshwaran by changing the archive scheme setting,we can choose the dev/debug sdk to generate the ipa file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If it helps someone :***

If you have separate release sdk and dev sdk, you can select either of them as required by editing the scheme setting (*Product->Scheme->edit scheme*).

As you can see in the image below,You can set the ***build configuration*** separately for running,testing,profiling,archiving etc.

For testing the release sdk,you can select the ***build configuration*** to ***release***  and properly setting the ***framework search path***,***header search path*** etc in the buildsettings and run the code.

By changing the archive scheme setting to release,we can choose the dev/debug sdk to generate the ipa file for development deployment(Check out the following link for more details).You may have to use the development provisioning profile to do so.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861275/can-i-debug-ios-app-installed-from-ipa-archive)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282655/can-ipa-file-be-created-in-debug-mode)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782266/how-to-debug-an-iphone-app-after-an-ad-hoc-build)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's very straightforward with Xcode:
[image]

For me it builds dylib release version this way. If you just do build, Xcode builds debug version.

David